# How to use -rpath in compile to set executables search shared library in its same directory

Tags: linux, compilation, shared-libraries, rpath

How to set executables search shared library in its same directory in compile,
I've put the executable file and related .so libraries in the same directory,  instead of changubg LD_LIBRARY_PATH or /etc/ld.so.conf, 
Is it possible to set -rpath as a variable which is the directory where keeps the executalbe file, and the variable is not a certain path , it's changable.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to set -rpath as a variable

Yes: you want `DT_RPATH` to be set to `$ORIGIN`, like so:

```
gcc main.c -Wl,-rpath='$ORIGIN' -lfoo -lbar
```

Note: you need to single-qoute the `$ORIGIN` to prevent shell from expanding it -- the `RPATH` *must* contain the `$` sign.

Another option is to link like so:

```
gcc main.c ./libfoo.so ./libbar.so
```

This will only work if `libfoo.so` and `libbar.so` do *not* have `DT_SONAME` set, and generally is an inferior solution. I am only mentioning it here for completeness.

Comment: I was looking for something like this. Thanks! Can I use: 
gcc main.c -Wl, -rpath=./my_folder/ -lfoo -lbar 

and shared the executable along with the ./my_folder folder and .so to someone else? Will they be able to use the file?

Comment: @programmer What you proposed: `-Wl,-rpath=./my_folder/` will _not_ work. Relative `RPATH` is a really bad idea(TM). But this is _probably_ what you want: `-Wl,-rpath='$ORIGIN/my_folder'`.